# Handling the different results from parsedatetime

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python after spending the last 15 or so years working only in Perl and only occasionally.

I can't understand how to handle the two different kinds of results from the parse method of Calendar.parse() from parsedatetime

Given this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import parsedatetime.parsedatetime as pdt
import parsedatetime.parsedatetime_consts as pdc
import sys
import os

# create an instance of Constants class so we can override some of the defaults

c = pdc.Constants()

# create an instance of the Calendar class and pass in our Constants # object instead of letting it create a default

p = pdt.Calendar(c)

while True:
 reply = raw_input('Enter text:')
 if reply == 'stop': 
  break
 else:
  result = p.parse(reply)
  print result
  print
```

And this sample run:

> Enter text:tomorrow
>   (time.struct_time(tm_year=2009, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=28, tm_hour=9, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=332, tm_isdst=-1), 1)
>
> Enter text:11/28
>   ((2009, 11, 28, 14, 42, 55, 4, 331, 0), 1)

I can't figure out how to get the output such that I can consisently use result like so:

```
print result[0].tm_mon, result[0].tm_mday
```

That won't work in the case where the input is "11/28" because the output is just a tuple and not a struct_time.

Probably a simple thing.. but not for this newbie.   From my perspective the output of Calendar.parse() is unpredictable and hard to use.   Any help appreciated.  Tia.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I ran into this yesterday and the answer here is incomplete (it will fail in the case that parse() returns a datetime).

From the parsedatetime docs:

parse() returns a tuple ( result, type ) where type specifies one of:

```
   0 = not parsed at all
   1 = parsed as a date (of type struct_time)
   2 = parsed as a time (of type struct_time)
   3 = parsed as a datetime (of type datetime.datetime)
```

Which is a little weird and maybe not the clearest way to do it, but it works and is pretty useful.

Here's a little chunk of code that will convert whatever it returns to a proper python datetime:

```
import parsedatetime.parsedatetime as pdt

def datetimeFromString( s ):

    c = pdt.Calendar()
    result, what = c.parse( s )

    dt = None

    # what was returned (see http://code-bear.com/code/parsedatetime/docs/)
    # 0 = failed to parse
    # 1 = date (with current time, as a struct_time)
    # 2 = time (with current date, as a struct_time)
    # 3 = datetime
    if what in (1,2):
        # result is struct_time
        dt = datetime.datetime( *result[:6] )
    elif what == 3:
        # result is a datetime
        dt = result

    if dt is None:
        # Failed to parse
        raise ValueError, ("Don't understand date '"+s+"'")

    return dt
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `x = time.struct_time(result[0])` and you'll get a `struct_time` (so that you can check `x.tm_mon` and `x.tm_mday`) no matter whether that `result[0]` is a `struct_time` itself, or just a 9-tuple (I've never heard of `parsedatetime` so I don't know why it's inconsistent in its return type, but with this simple approach you can neutralize that inconsistency).

Comment: Thank you.  That got me over my hurdle.

Perhaps I should have asked if parsedatetime is the preferred method of parsing human formatted dates (e.g. "next tuesday").   It's what I found, but being new to the python community judging the reputation of libraries is hard for me still.

http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/
http://code-bear.com/code/parsedatetime/

Comment: parsedatetime returns a tuple with the appropriate date/time value based on the text it parsed.  I wrote it to return a time, date or datetime so that the caller would only get the information that was present in the text - if I always returned a datetime item then I would have to fill in values for items that may have not been present.

It's a little odd, but it worked for us (OSAF) back when when I wrote it :)